Customize Error with value of other json path value
When validating a json array the error gives a path with an index value
eg, [0].citation.violation.location
is there a way to get the value of a different path for the same index and append it to the message?
(for example [0].citation.number)?
i have a placeholder in the code below for "senderEcitationNumber", which I am trying to get but haven't figured out if it is possible.
SchemaValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler = (sender, args) => messages.Add( new JsonValidationErrorInfo
{
    senderEcitationNumber = sender.ToString(), //placeholder
    JsonPath = args.Path,
    JsonValidationError = args.ValidationError,
    JsonValidationMessage = args.Message
});

